# HMM forward algorithm in R

Tags: r, probability, hidden-markov-model, forward-backward

maybe a very basic hmm implementation question.

Would there be a way to determine the most 'likely' of two different HMMs for a specific sequence? I was thinking about using the forward algorithm through the 'HMM' package in R. However using the forward function gets me a table rather than a single probability

```
# Initialise HMM
library(HMM)
hmm = initHMM(c("A","B"), c("L","R"),          
transProbs=matrix(c(.8,.2,.2,.8),2),
emissionProbs=matrix(c(.6,.4,.4,.6),2))
print(hmm)
# Sequence of observations
observations = c("L","L","R","R")
# Calculate forward probablities
logForwardProbabilities = forward(hmm,observations)
print(exp(logForwardProbabilities))


 index
states   1     2      3        4
 A 0.3 0.168 0.0608 0.024448
 B 0.2 0.088 0.0624 0.037248
```

How would I reform this into some sort of single likelihood value I could compare with the results of another hmm run on the same sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the sum of the last column (0.061696). This can also be done using the aphid package as follows:

```
library(aphid)
states <- c("Begin", "A", "B")
residues <- paste(c("L", "R"))
A <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.8, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.8), nrow = 3)
dimnames(A) <- list(from = states, to = states)
E <- matrix(c(0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6), nrow = 2)
dimnames(E) <- list(states = states[-1], residues = residues)
hmm <- structure(list(A = A, E = E), class = "HMM")
forward(hmm, observations)
```

This prints:

```
> Full (log) probability of sequence given model = -2.785536
```

The returned object is a list featuring the log odds score and the dynamic programming array.